# Is Code with Reference Types thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I would like to know if this code is thread safe? I guess yes because Reference Types are thread safe. But in this case, since it is a generic, we can't be sure right?

```
 public class LifoMsgQueue<T>
    {
        private class Node<E>
        {
            internal Node<E> next;
            internal E msg;
            internal Node(E msg)
            {
                this.msg = msg;
            }
        }
        private Node<T> top;
        public void Send(T msg)
        {
            Node<T> node = new Node<T>(msg);
            node.next = top;
            top = node;
        }
        public T Receive()
        {
            SpinWait sw = new SpinWait();
            Node<T> oldTop;
            while ((oldTop = top) == null)
                sw.SpinOnce();
            top = oldTop.next;
            return oldTop.msg;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Reference Types are thread safe"!?

Comment: If two threads call `Send` at the same time, it's all over.

Comment: Without any synchronization shown  it is unlikely this code is thread safe. Using local `SpinWait sw` variable does not count as synchronization.

Comment: "Reads and writes of the following data types are atomic: bool, char, byte, sbyte, short, ushort, uint, int, float, and reference types. " taken from MSDN website.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz or receive...

Comment: What should I do to become thread safe?

Comment: @AndreRoque That is when dealing with a single operation on a single line of code, when you have more than one line/operation it does not apply. If you want to be thread safe you need to use a `lock` around `Send` and part of `Receive`

Comment: @AndreRoque atomic and thread safe are somewhat unrelated concepts.

Comment: I highly reccomend you read the blog post "[What is this thing you call "thread safe"?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe/)", if you want to know if a peice of code is thread safe you need to learn what thread safe means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way, I think, to make your code thread-safe would be to replace any usage of your custom "LifoMsgQueue<T>" with the System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentStack<T> class, which would do the same thing.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267331(v=vs.110).aspx

> Represents a thread-safe last in-first out (LIFO) collection.

If you want to make your class thread-safe then you would need to investigate locking mechanisms, such as the lock keyword.

Answer (score 4):

If you have multiple concurrent "producers" (callers of Send()) then this is by no means safe. Two threads can see the same .top, or race to overwrite it.

If you have multiple "consumers" (not as common, but you didn't specify exactly just what degree of safety you seek, eg: 1 consumer x 1 producer, 1 consumer x N producers, N consumers x 1 producer, N consumers x N producers) you are at risk of duplicating messages.

The use of generics here is of no consequence. While with reference types you cannot screw up reads (they will be atomic, as object references are just a word long, and Node is a class), you're susceptible to race conditions.

The static class Interlocked has a number of tools that can alleviate these issues, should you be interested in implementing this yourself rather than relying on the IProducerConsumer facilities.